# Map Date Field in Typescript to a DateTime Field in C# at backend

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm building an angular application with .NET core at backend. I have a Model with a "DateTime" property at C# backend. I build a component and a model at fronend with property of "Date" at Typescript.

I built a form to get this date as input field, but i can't perform the http post due to issues with date typys mapping between fronend/backend models

Answer (score 0):

It has taken me hours to find a reasonable solution, but what worked for me in the end was using the DatePipe to format the date before loading the form (to set the default date in a usable format). This will populate the 'date' input type correctly and send the date to an MVC API method is a manner that it can properly be parsed. The relevant steps are:

1. import the DatePipe
2. inject the DatePipe
3. transform the date / dates
4. populate the form

The DatePipe also needs to be added in the providers section of app.modules.ts

In the TypeScript component:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
...
constructor(
    private myService: MyService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private datePipe: DatePipe
...
getMyRequest(id): void {
    this.myService.getActivityHeaderRequest(id)
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.myRequest = x;
        var _startDate = this.datePipe.transform(x.validFromDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
this.bookNowForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          requestId: [x.requestId],
          startDate: _startDate
...
```